# Access lower layer output in higher layer using CNTK and transfer learning

Tags: python, deep-learning, cntk

I am searching for a way to forward lower layer output to a higher layer with a loaded VGG16 model using CNTK.

***The background of my problem is:***

I reimplemented some parts of [Fully Convolutional Networks for Semantic Segmentation](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonlong/long_shelhamer_fcn.pdf) but then I ran into some problems: Starting with [this example](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Examples/Image/Classification/VGG/Python/VGG16_ImageNet_Distributed.py) I first replaced the fully connected layers with fully convolutional and slit the sequence in the model definition part into chunks where I could simply access `pool3` and `pool4` for the later usage in eg. `Convolution2D((1,1), num_classes, name='score_pool4')(pool4)`. This works fine but after building the model I noticed, that I need to implement an own way to read batches because the build-in reader does not support 2D labels right now. Now I simply read the images using OpenCV and replaced the `training_session(...).train()` with a for loop and `trainer.train_minibatch({model['features']: my_loaded_features, model['labels']: my_2D_labels})` this works well **but** because of the removed `training_session` part I don't know where I could apply the existing VGG16 weights.

***My problem is:***

I searched for [transfer learning examples](https://www.cntk.ai/pythondocs/CNTK_301_Image_Recognition_with_Deep_Transfer_Learning.html) where those guys load models using `C.load_model(...)` and then clone the needed layers but now I am wondering how could I access *cloned_layers->pool4* (in the middle of the loaded model) if I also want to use it in deeper layers.

I tried `Convolution2D((1,1), num_classes, name='score_pool4')(cloned_layers.find_by_name('pool4'))`but I ended up with some error messages while learner initialization because of "unknown shape information" in used weight variables.

So how can I access those layers within the loaded model for later (deeper) usage?

Thanks for reading (and maybe helping)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to read custom data. There are two tutorials on building your own readers. https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/manuals.html

Regarding cloning parts of a network - [here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46311945/cloning-a-cntk-node-to-test-it-in-isolation/46333146#46333146) to another post on StackOverflow that has exemplar code